# OnChange Select double calls ajax php request

Tags: jquery, ajax

Strange Problem;-) Have some select drop Downs which on change i call an ajax php request to make some MySQL. Unfortunately, the code always double submit the ajax-call so i get double results.

any idea, whats wrong?

Select:

```
<div id="select_uhren" class="row">

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <!-- HERSTELLER -->
                <select class="fselect ffilter" id="fbrand" name="fbrand"><option value="">Alle Hersteller</option><option value="18">DIESEL</option><option value="15">EMPORIO ARMANI</option></select>                    </div><!--end col 3 -->

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <!-- TYP -->
                <select id="ftyp" class="fselect ffilter" name="ftyp"><option value="">Typ/Geschlecht</option><option value="male">Herren</option><option value="female">Frauen</option></select>                    </div><!--end col 3 -->


                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <!-- MATERIAL -->
                  <select id="fmaterial" class="fselect ffilter" name="fmaterial"><option value="">Alle Materialien</option><option value="10">Edelstahl</option><option value="127">Keramik</option></select>                    </div><!--end col 3 -->

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <!-- STATUS  -->
                  <select id="fstatus" class="fselect ffilter" name="fstatus"><option value="">Status</option><option value="limited">Limitiert</option><option value="neu">Neu</option></select>                    </div><!--end col 3  -->    

            </div>
```

jQuery Ajax-Call:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('.ffilter').change(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var fbrand = $('#fbrand').val();
    var ftyp = $('#ftyp').val();
    var fmaterial = $('#fmaterial').val();
    var fstatus = $('#fstatus').val();
    var jetzt = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(fbrand);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'application/inc/fun.filter.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: { varb: fbrand, vtyp: ftyp, vmat: fmaterial, vsta: fstatus, vjetzt: jetzt },
      context: this,
      success: function(data) {
          console.log(fbrand);
           $('.productoverview').html(data);
           $("img").unveil();
      }
    })

  });
```

});

Thanks for help

beste regards
thomas

Comment: hi you should try by make change call with unbind and bind else you can call change event with **on('change',function(){
})** this might will work for you

Answer (score 1):

I've actually had the same problem yesterday. Try to unbind the event first, it actually helped in my case.

Try to change 
$('.ffilter').change(function(e) {
into
$('.ffilter').unbind("change").change(function(e) {
or
$('.ffilter').unbind("change").on("change", function(e) {